# How to reorder PDF document pages?

Tags: javascript, c#, pdf

I'm trying to reorder the pages of a pdf that I have. There are 716 pages and each page is numbered. Not all pages are numbered in the same location but they're numbered in thre "styles". I'm wondering how I would go about reordering the pages based on the page number on the page in the document? The pdf page numbers are editable text.

Here is an example of the three styles:

[image: Top Right Corner]

[image: Top Left Corner]

[image: Bot Left Corner]

I've seen a few posts about creating bookmarks. I've found a plugin that can create bookmarks based on some text style called autobookmark plugin. I'm just not sure what direction to go in on this. There are too many pages to do this by hand.

Page numbers being edited:

[image: How it looks when editing the page number]

Comment: *The pdf page numbers are editable text.* - what do you mean by that? Are they form field values?

Comment: Are you willing to edit this document in browser or by c# code?

Comment: I'm not sure if they're form fields or not, I don't think they are...just text boxes like my edit in the question.

@profesor79 I am willing to do this any way that works!

Comment: Essentially you have to determine the nature of the page numbers (are they part of the content? Are they some kind of annotation?). Then you can use a Pdf library (PdfSharp recommended in the answer is one option of many) to automatically identify the page number and reorder the pages based on that information. As soon as you have decided on a particular pdf library and become stuck implementing that, you can ask a question here which is more precise, not *unclear*.

Answer (score 2):

What I could propose here is [PDFSharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsharp/). This library will allow you to open pdf file, split by pages and then sort.

If I get it wright, the pages in input document aren't sorted - so it will be nice task to dump pdf page to text file first (for all three cases) and see how hard it will be to extract page number block (regex, or pdf language markups).

And last step - create new document with pages sorted by new number

From the above referenced sourceforge repository:

> Description
>
> PDFsharp is a .NET library for creating and modifying Adobe PDF documents programmatically from any .NET language like C# or VB.NET.
>   PDFsharp defines classes for the objects found in PDF files, so you
>   never have to deal with IDs or references directly.

It was last updated Dec 2015

Comment: PDFSharp would be my recommendation also. The API is quite simple to learn.

Comment: Be very careful with these types of answers profesor79. They tend to attract heat.

Comment: Some on your latest answers are clearly for off-topic questions. This could attract you some downvotes. Such questions should not be answered. Feel free to come to the [Campaigns](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290/campaigns) chat room if you want to discuss this.